# PHP or JS screenshots/snapshots

Tags: javascript, php, screenshot, snapshot

My final project at university consists in analyze some screenshots of my feeds in various social networks. As i need periodic screenshots, I'd like to write a script which login in the social network and saves the printscreen on the server.
I have already studied many of APIs like html2canvas, but I'm having trouble to screenshot crendential needed pages.
Do someone has any idea what can I use??

Thankss (:

Comment: Why do you need a screenshot, instead of a copy of the feed in plaintext/xml ? XML is machine readable, screenshot is not ment to be. To login for example into facebook, facebook provides an API to login. If you are using a macro language like AutoIT, just send the credentials to the inputs and send a button-hit / "enter" event. To get a better answer, you should specify the problem you encounter and show what exactly you tried (include sourecode).

Comment: I need the images, cause I will analyze this images with a visual attention model

Answer (score 1):

Since I was asked to write somthing more then just a link here ist comes:
It is quite easy to capture screens from websites using JavaScript and PhantomJS, which you can find here: http://phantomjs.org

The following script demonstrates the simplest use of page capture. It loads the Stackoverflow homepage and then saves it as an image, stackoverflow.png.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://stackoverflow.com/', function() {
  page.render('stackoverflow.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

You can download PhantomJS at http://phantomjs.org which also provides explanation how to get it running on your system.

Comment: Please don't provide link-only-answers. Provide enough information to really answer the question. Links can always break. (you can quote from your link and leave the link there for reference)

Comment: Point taken and answer edited. Sorry, it was my first answer here.

Comment: No problem, this can help you next time: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer